# Посоветуйте ресурс по работе с моделями данных

Tags: алгоритм, модель-данных

Наткнулся на задачку по выбору случайного элемента массива с учетом веса элементов массива. Решение было в сложении веса элементов массива в так называемую ось X и выделением диапазона для каждого элемента на этой оси. Далее просто бросали случайно число от Xmin до Xmax и определяли, диапазону какого элемента принадлежит это число. Решение показалось мне очень изящным, но скорее всего оно не ново.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, книгу или м.б. интернет ресурс, где можно было бы научиться так же ловко представлять данные для решения различных задач.

Comment: [Algorithms, 4th Edition](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/) - лучшее, что я видел. А видел я немало. На курсере есть ещё и курсы по этой книге с этими же авторами - из 2 частей. Сама книга есть на русском. Кормены/Кнуты - это для академиков, хотите разбираться в алгоритмах на достаточном для понимания алгоритмов уровне - читайте эту книгу / проходите курсы по ней.

Comment: Если хотите просто понять что на практике означает знать алгоритмы, советую 2 книги - 1) Скиена - Алгоритмы. Руководство по разработке. Тут много примеров и историй из жизни, некоторые сломают вам мозг. 2) Бентли - Жемчужины программирования. Я решил учить алгоритмы после этой книги.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответы! Буду изучать материал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу новизны или нет.

[Закон Стиглера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) (принципом Арнольда)

**Никакое научное открытие не было названо в честь первооткрывателя**

это чтоб не питать иллюзий.

по ресурсам. их много и однозначности это не добавит. Предлагаю несколько ресурсов. Моё личное предпочтение не согласные добавляйте ответы.

1. Дональд Кнут: Искусство программирования.
2. Поитересуйтесь спортивным программированием ([Спортивное программирование: «С чего начать?»](https://habr.com/ru/post/128108/)). Считаю что в спортивном программировании много интересных задач именно для развития.
3. ......

Comment: Советовать Кнута новичку - это сильно. Это больше наверное отобъет желание вообще лезть в алгоритмы. Я когда нибудь дочитаю его, когда буду на пенсии наверное :)

Comment: Артем алгоритмы вещь не простая. Нужно же счего начинать алгоритмы. Отбить желание может что угодно. Теорема Гёлдера или не существование решения для большинства задач и прочая не очень мотивирующая лабуда. Нужно любить своё дело, не важно какое оно. И не останавливаться перед преградами. Когда в большинстве случаев существует обход( workaround )

Comment: Это все правильно говоришь, то это никак не относится к тому факту, что книги Кнута больше для избранных фанатов или исследователей с бекграундом.

Comment: Меня учили если не понимаешь выучи. Память у человека ассоциативная. Просто для переваривания порой требуется время. Кнут это лишь совет и пример того что не все так просто в теории. Я заканчивал прикладную математику и понимал что мы не используем толком и части фундаментальной математики. А почему? Нет необходимости в производство. Нет необходимости знать с точностью до грамма сколько уйдет цемента на сройке. Так вот знание всего Кнута нет необходимости, поскольку большинство решённых задач давно реализованы.

Comment: Вот с этим согласен. Знать Кнута нет никакой необходимости :)